# Interpreting Bonnie++ test result

Tags: file

I would like to understand the bonnie++ test result in detail. I could not find much detail in the manual page [bon_csv2html Man Page](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/bonnie++/bon_csv2html.1.en.html). I also got this link [Bonnie++ Documentation](http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/readme.html) but couldn't understand it properly. Could some one please elaborate the columns given in bonnie++ result. Below is the screenshot of result[image]